# Python: List of Dictionary Mapping

Tags: python, json, dictionary, optimization, mapping

I have a list of 10,000 Dictionaries from a JSON that look like:

```
my_list =
[
    {"id": 1, "val": "A"},
    {"id": 4, "val": "A"},
    {"id": 1, "val": "C"},
    {"id": 3, "val": "C"},
    {"id": 1, "val": "B"},
    {"id": 2, "val": "B"},
    {"id": 4, "val": "C"},
    {"id": 4, "val": "B"},
    .
    .
    .
    {"id": 10000, "val": "A"}
]
```

and I want my output to be:

```
mapped_list =
[
    {"id": 1, "val": ["A", "B", "C"]},
    {"id": 2, "val": ["B"]},
    {"id": 3, "val": ["C"]},
    {"id": 4, "val": ["A", "B", "C"]},
    .
    .
    .
    {"id": 10000, "val": ["A","C"]}
]
```

My goal is to Map the first list's "id" and its "val" to create the 2nd list as efficiently as possible. So far my running time has not been the greatest:

```
output = []
cache = {}

for unit in my_list:
    uid = unit['id']
    value = unit['val']

    if (uid in cache):
        output[uid][value].append(value)
    else:
        cache[uid] = 1
        output.append({'id' : uid, 'values': value})
```

My approach is to make a frequency check of the 'id' to avoid iterating through 2 different lists. I believe my fault is in understanding nested dicts/lists of dicts. I have a feeling I can get this in O(n), if not better, as O(n^2) is out of the question its too easy to grow this in magnitude.

Brighten my insight PLEASE, I could use the help.
Or any other way of approaching this problem.
Maybe map(), zip(), tuple() might be a better approach for this. Let me know!

EDIT: I'm trying to accomplish this with only built-in functions. Also, the last dictionary is to exemplify that this is not limited to what I have displayed but there are more "id's" than I can share with "val" being a combination of A,B,C for whatever id its associated with.

UPDATE:

This is my final solution, if there can be any improvements, Let me know!

```
    mapped_list = []
    cache = {}

    for item in my_list:
        id = item['id']
        val = item['val']

        if (id in cache):
            output[cache[id]]['val'].append(val)
        else:
            cache[id] = len(output)
            mapped_list.append({'id' : id, 'val': [val]})

    mapped_list.sort(key=lambda k: k['id'])
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_list=[
    {"id": 1, "val": 'A'},
    {"id": 4, "val": "A"},
    {"id": 1, "val": "C"},
    {"id": 3, "val": "C"},
    {"id": 1, "val": "B"},
    {"id": 2, "val": "B"},
    {"id": 4, "val": "C"},
    {"id": 4, "val": "B"},
    {"id": 10000, "val": "A"}
]

temp_dict = {}
for item in my_list:
  n, q = item.values()
  if not n in temp_dict:
    temp_dict[n] = []
  temp_dict.get(n,[]).append(q)

mapped_list = [{'id': n, 'val': q} for n,q in temp_dict.items()]
mapped_list = sorted(mapped_list, key = lambda x : x['id'])
print(mapped_list)
```

Comment: This was how I was thinking about the problem and the approach I had in my head. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `collections.defaultdict` like,

```
>>> my_list
[{'id': 1, 'val': 'A'}, {'id': 4, 'val': 'A'}, {'id': 1, 'val': 'C'}, {'id': 3, 'val': 'C'}, {'id': 1, 'val': 'B'}, {'id': 2, 'val': 'B'}, {'id': 4, 'val': 'C'}, {'id': 4, 'val': 'B'}, {'id': 10000, 'val': 'A'}]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in my_list:
...   d[item['id']].append(item['val'])
... 
>>> mapped_list = [{'id': key, 'val': val} for key,val in d.items()]
>>> mapped_list = sorted(mapped_list, key=lambda x: x['id']) # just to make it always sorted by `id`
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(mapped_list)
[{'id': 1, 'val': ['A', 'C', 'B']},
 {'id': 2, 'val': ['B']},
 {'id': 3, 'val': ['C']},
 {'id': 4, 'val': ['A', 'C', 'B']},
 {'id': 10000, 'val': ['A']}]
```

Comment: you can put `sorted` around `d.items()`, which saves a little time vs. sorting separately on the next line

Comment: Not really. The time difference will be really really small. And that's micro optimization. I'd rather have a code that is readable, and then if it requires optimization, then work on that : )

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple `val` with the same `id` you can use a set like this:

```
my_list = [
    {"id": 1, "val": "A"},
    {"id": 4, "val": "A"},
    {"id": 1, "val": "C"},
    {"id": 3, "val": "C"},
    {"id": 1, "val": "B"},
    {"id": 2, "val": "B"},
    {"id": 4, "val": "C"},
    {"id": 4, "val": "B"},
    {"id": 10000, "val": "A"}
]

from collections import defaultdict
ddict = defaultdict(set)
for lst in my_list:
    ddict[lst['id']].add(lst['val'])

result = [{"id" : k,"val" : list(v)} for k,v in ddict.items()]
sorted(result,key = lambda x : x['id'])

[{'id': 1, 'val': ['C', 'A', 'B']},
 {'id': 2, 'val': ['B']},
 {'id': 3, 'val': ['C']},
 {'id': 4, 'val': ['C', 'A', 'B']},
 {'id': 10000, 'val': ['A']}]
```

Insert or search in `dict` (or `defaultdict`) and `set` have `O(1)` complexity and the sort function have `O(NlogN)` so overall is `O(N + NlogN)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't be able to do it better than `O(n*log(n))`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

vals = defaultdict(list)
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['val'])

for i in my_list:
    vals[i['id']].append(i['val'])

output = [{'id': k, 'val': v} for k, v in vals.items()]
output.sort(key=lambda x: x['id'])
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'val': ['A', 'B', 'C']},
 {'id': 2, 'val': ['B']},
 {'id': 3, 'val': ['C']},
 {'id': 4, 'val': ['A', 'B', 'C']},
 {'id': 1000, 'val': ['A']}]
```

Comment: why use 'my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['val'])' here.without this statement will get answer

Comment: @aslamsha22 take a look at `val` lists in the output `mapped_list` dictionaries, they are sorted.

Comment: :yes they are sorted. but with out 'my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['val'])'
 this statement get sorted values in output.here not required this sort based on 'val'.

Comment: Just compare my output with ones provided by other answers and you'll see the difference.

Comment: yes, i found that your and han solo's answers are almost similar.your sort makes different.anyway both are good answers

Answer (score 0):

I am created mapped_list using **setdefault**

```
d = {}
for i in my_list:
    d.setdefault(i['id'], []).append(i['val'])
mapped_list = [{'id':key, 'val': val} for key,val in sorted(d.items())]
print(mapped_list)
```

**defaultdict** makes better performance than **setdefault**.

I just make this answer for creating mapped_list using another approach